# Linux terminal: Keyboard shortcut for moving across tabs

Tags: linux, terminal, centos

Is there any way to move across the different tabs in linux(CentOS) terminal like `Ctrl + Tab` for moving across different tabs in web browsers.

I have tried `Alt + 1` , `Alt +2` etc... for moving along the ordered tabs. But it will not work more than nine tabs.

Is there any other keyboard shortcut to move across the tabs ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Mac, you can do Cmd + left/right arrow

If you're using Linux, you can do Ctrl + page up/page down or left/right arrow

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Yes... Ctrl + pageup/pagedown is working...
Ctrl + left/right is not working with CentOS..

Comment: Kewl! :-) good to hear Ctrl + pageup/pagedown is working for you, could you try Ctrl + Shift + left/right arrow and let me know what happens? It should work

Comment: Nop... Ctrl + Shift + Right is printing C and Ctrl + Shift + Left is printing D in the same tab. No changes in tab. :(

Comment: But Ctrl + page up and page down is working super with CentOS. thanqq so much...